# Laravel запрос в БД с помощью Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, querybuilder

Всем привет. Осваиваю Laravel и столкнулся с следующей проблемой.
Есть запрос на Query Builder, который вытягивает информацию с БД. 
Пример:

```
public function getFoodTypesListByCountObject($countryId = false, $cityId = false, $regionId = false, $dateFrom = false, $dateTo = false, $person = false)
{

    $objectsFoodTypes = DB::table('food_types AS ft')
        ->select('ft.id', 'ft.name', DB::raw('count(DISTINCT o.id) as countObject'))
        ->join('objects AS o', 'ft.id', '=', 'o.foodTypesId')
        ->join('rooms AS r', 'o.id', '=', 'r.objectId')
        ->where([
            ['o.countryId', '=', $countryId],
            ['o.cityId', '=', $cityId],
            ['o.regionId', '=', $regionId],
            ['o.person', '=', $person],
        ])
        ->groupBy('ft.id')
        ->get();

    return $objectsFoodTypes;
}
```

Из реквеста приходят параметры, от которых зависит вывод информации на страничке. Не могу разобраться как в Laravel исключать параметр из массива where([['o.person', '=', $person]]) , если например вместо значения параметра $person пришел false.
В сыром запросе можно делать все так:

```
public function getListObjects($countryId, $cityId = false, $regionId = false, $dateFrom = false, $dateTo = false, $person = false) {

    $sql = "SELECT *
                            FROM objects AS o
                            JOIN cities AS c ON o.`cityId` = c.`id`                               
                            WHERE 
                                    o.`valuePercent` =  50 ".
                            (($countryId) ? " AND c.countryId = " . $countryId : "") .
                            (($cityId) ? " AND c.id = " . $cityId : "") .
                            (($regionId) ? " AND c.regionId  = " . $regionId : "") .
                            (($person) ? " AND r.amountPerson  = " . $person : "") .                                
                            AND (o.price > 0 AND o.price <=2000)
                            GROUP BY o.id";

    $objects = DB::select($sql);
    return $objects;
}
```

Подскажите как средствами Laravel подобное, на примере первого запроса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно Query Builder разбить на части и тогда спокойно делать ваши проверки:

```
$query = DB::table('food_types AS ft')
    ->select('ft.id', 'ft.name', DB::raw('count(DISTINCT o.id) as countObject'))
    ->join('objects AS o', 'ft.id', '=', 'o.foodTypesId')
    ->join('rooms AS r', 'o.id', '=', 'r.objectId');
if ($person) {
    $query->where('o.person', $person);
}
//Остальные проверки по аналогии с этой

$objectsFoodTypes = $query->groupBy('ft.id')->get();
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.

Comment: А возможно как то эти проверки вынести в отдельную функцию, а потом просто ее вызывать, там где нужно. Чтоб не дублировать код?

Comment: Почему бы и нет

Comment: Все сделал, просто не работал с Query Builder, поэтому не совсем понятен его синтаксис. Вроде разобрался.